# Reusable Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm building reusable function, but I can't change global variables values.

```
var foo = 5;
function MyFunction(arg) {
  setInterval(function(){
     foo = 2 + arg;
     return foo;

  }) ;

}

foo = MyFunction(1);
alert( foo );
```

After function complete I'm getting undefined;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are global variable in this, i could not find one

Comment: @valarmorghulis: `foo` is global as shown...

Comment: I am getting undefined

Comment: `var foo` not global, only `foo` thats global

Comment: Either add a return statement in your function or don't redeclare `foo` to being `MyFunction`.

Comment: Ok, actually I have tried to simplify my question, but now I see that the problem is that I set interval in this function. And then it returns undefined. Updated my question.

Answer (score 6):

```js
var foo = 5;
function MyFunction(arg) {
   foo = 2 + arg;
}

MyFunction(1);
alert( foo );
```

You assigned the result of `MyFunction` invocation to `foo` and that's why you got `undefined`. `MyFunction` has no `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

In order to define a global variable you can use variable name without `var` keyword or define the variable outside any function scope. Then you can access it by the given method :

```
foo = 5;
function MyFunction(arg) {
   window.foo = 2 + arg;
}

MyFunction(1);
alert( window.foo );
```

Note: Now `foo` is a part of window object.

Comment: Yes, but that was not the problem. But depending on the scope, `var foo` could already be global.

Comment: The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: yes i see that was not the problem yet i thought it would be great to share a thing or two of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

ekuusela gives the right answer as to why your (presumably simplified) example doesn't work.

There are lots of reasons why you could have problems with globals, the most common being that you are accidentally clobbering a global by using the same identifier in some other function, and forgetting to declare it locally.  To this day I still get problems where I've written `for (i=0;i<n;i++)` without first declaring `var i` in that function-- which then uses a global `i`, and works fine until 6 months later I make the same mistake somewhere else...

As a useful tip for debugging, the expression `var G = (function(){return this})()` will always give you the global object, no matter where you run it, including eval'd code.  You can then access the global variable `foo` as `G.foo`, evaluate `('foo' in G)` to check whether such a global exists, and so on.